# irrational numbers

Tags: general-topology

The set of irrational numbers  $\mathbb{P}$ is uncountable.So, $\mathbb{P}\times \mathbb{P}$
is uncountable. I wonder that is there any topological space in which $\mathbb{P}\times \mathbb{P}$ is lindelof? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Bbb R^2$ is second countable and therefore hereditarily Lindelöf, so $\Bbb P\times\Bbb P$ is hereditarily Lindelöf as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$.

As a matter of fact, $\Bbb P$ with the usual topology is homeomorphic to $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$, the Cartesian product of countably infinitely many copies of $\Bbb N$ with the product topology, and $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}\times\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ is also just the Cartesian product of countably infinitely many copies of $\Bbb N$, so $\Bbb P\times\Bbb P$ is actually homeomorphic to $\Bbb P$ itself, which is hereditarily Lindelöf as a subspace of the second countable space $\Bbb R$. (Here $\Bbb N$ has the discrete topology.)

Comment: every second countable regular space is lindelof,so  the axiom  of regularity is also necessary, isn't it?

Comment: @ghb: No, second countability is enough. Let $X$ be second countable, with countable base $\mathscr{B}$, and let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $X$. Let $\mathscr{B}_0=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:\exists U\in\mathscr{U}(B\subseteq U)\}$. Since $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the topology, $\mathscr{B}_0$ covers $X$, and clearly $\mathscr{B}_0$ is countable. For each $B\in\mathscr{B}_0$ fix a $U_B\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $B\subseteq U_B$, and let $\mathscr{U}_0=\{U_B:B\in\mathscr{B}_0\}$. Then $\mathscr{U}_0$ is a countable subset of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $X$.

Comment: You are right,but in the book of Engelking's, regularity is necessary.

Comment: @ghb: That’s because he defines *Lindelöf* to mean that every open cover has a countable subcover **and** the space is regular. For most of us *Lindelöf* simply means that every open cover has a countable subcover. (This is one of the few really annoying things about that book; it’s a wonderful reference, but it does have a few odd quirks.)

Comment: @ghb: You’re very welcome.

Comment: I also want to ask to you $\mathbb{P}\times \mathbb{P}$ is metrizable subspace in sorgenfrey plane?

Comment: @ghb: No, it’s not even a normal subspace of the Sorgenfrey plane. The proofs that the Sorgenfrey plane not normal can be adapted to $\Bbb P\times\Bbb P$.